# How do I make a horizontal line span most of the document up to the margins?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

I added this line:

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.6pt}}
```

but this spans the entire document. I would like it to stop at a margin. Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}% For reference of the text block margins

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% For this example

\begin{document}

A:% Rule across entire text block

\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}

B: % Rule from left margin across entire page

\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\rule{\paperwidth}{.4pt}}

C: % Rule from left margin across entire text block + 2cm

\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm}{.4pt}}

D:% Rule from right margin across entire page

\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}

E:% Rule from right margin across entire text block + 2em

\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+2em}{0.4pt}}

\end{document}
```

The use of `\paperwidth` is actually much wider than is needed, setting the rule *off* the page.

The main principle behind aligning the rules to the margins is to set a box that is either `l`eft or `r`ight aligned. Then the length of the rule can be adjusted to reach the desired effect (overrun on the right or left, say).